# How can I statically import methods in code generated by Xtend active annotations?

Tags: xtend

I would like to use a statically imported method in code generated with Xtend's active annotations. As an example, I want to get this output:

```
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

@MyActiveAnnotation
public class MyTest {

    public void foo() {
        emptyList();
    }
}
```

My compilation participant looks like this:

```
override doTransform(MutableClassDeclaration clazz, extension TransformationContext context) {
clazz.addMethod("foo", [
    body = '''
        «Collections».emptyList();
])
```

While this code works and imports `Collections`, it doesn't statically import the `emptyList` method.

How can I statically import methods using Xtend's active annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Xtend developers, this [doesn't seem possible](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1093252&goto=1786945&#msg_1786945).